# SWT Browser is not rendering Angular 2 pages inside eclipse view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, swt, eclipse-rcp

I was trying to include the Angular 2 HTML pages inside the SWT Browser widget. 
Looks like the angular 2 HTML pages are not being rendered inside the SWT Browser.

However, I was able to include the Angular 1 (or Angular JS) pages inside the SWT browser widget without any major issues.

This is my HTML page where in the `<body>`I have defined the angular component selector `app-root>` which resides under the app folder where the component's type script (.ts) file resides.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Composer Bulk Manager</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Is there any limitation to SWT Browser with Angular framework ( ie.., with Angular 2 and above ) ??

Answer (score 1):

SWT Browser by default takes InternExplorer. 
IE doesnot support ES6.
To workaround you have to enable some of the imports in the 'polyfills.ts'

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```